# borei menei b’samim, flowers and fresh mowed grass

Tags: halacha, blessing, agriculture, smell

1. Someone told me that if one stops to smell the flowers he should remember to make the *borei menei b’samim.* Where is the source for this in *halacha*?
2. Does one make *borei menei b’samim* if he enjoys the aroma of fresh mowed grass or passes a lawn that is being mowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch - in סימן נח - דין ברכת הריח.

> סעיף א': כְּשֵׁם שֶׁאָסוּר לְאָדָם לֵהָנוֹת מִמַּאֲכָל אוֹ מַשְׁקֶה קֹדֶם שֶׁיְבָרֵךְ, כָּךְ אָסוּר לוֹ לֵהָנוֹת מֵרֵיחַ טוֹב קֹדֶם שֶׁיְבָרֵךְ, עָלָיו, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר, כָּל הַנְּשָׁמָה תְּהַלֵּל יָה. אֵיזֶהוּ דָּבָר שֶׁהַנְּשָׁמָה נֶהֱנֵית מִמֶּנּוּ וְאֵין הַגּוּף נֶהֱנֶה מִמֶּנּוּ. הֱוֵי אוֹמֵר, זֶה הָרֵיחַ.‏

One may not benefit from a good smell without making a Bracha on it.

> סעיף יב': הַנִּכְנָס לְתוֹךְ חֲנוּת שֶׁל בְּשָׂמִים אוֹ (אַפָּאטָהעק) בֵּית מִרְקַחַת וְנִתְכַּוֵּן לְהָרִיחַ, מְבָרֵךְ בּוֹרֵא מִינֵי בְּשָׂמִים

Anything one stops to smell needs a Bracha - even entering a flower store to enjoy the smell warrants a Bracha.

However, perfumes used to hide an unpleasant odor, or a perfume warehouse - where they do not expect you to come in and enjoy the smell - do not warrant a Bracha.

> סעיף י': [...] וְדַוְקָא כְּשֶׁמֻּגְמָר בִּשְׁבִיל לְהָרִיחַ, אֲבָל מַה שֶּׁמְעַשְׁנִין בִּשְׁבִיל לְבַטֵּל הַסִּרְחוֹן כְּדֶרֶךְ שֶׁנּוֹתְנִין בְּשָׂמִים אֵצֶל הַמֵּתִים, אֵין מְבָרְכִין עָלָיו כְּלָל. ‏
>
> : סעיף יא' וְכֵן כָּל דָּבָר שֶׁאֵינוֹ עוֹמֵד לְהָרִיחַ, כְּגוֹן בְּשָׂמִים הַמֻּנָּחִים בַּחֶדֶר לִסְחוֹרָה, וְכֵן מֻגְמָר שֶׁמְגַמְּרִין בּוֹ אֶת הַכֵּלִים, שֶׁלֹּא נַעֲשָׂה לְהָרִיחַ בְּעַצְמוֹ, רַק לִתֵּן רֵיחַ בַּכֵּלִים, אֵין מְבָרְכִין עֲלֵיהֶם, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא מִתְכַּוֵּן לְהָרִיחַ. ‏

The details are then in the other 17 Se'ifim.

Note, however, that the Bracha on flowers is not necessarily בּוֹרֵא מִינֵי בְּשָׂמִים!

If it's a tree, then it's בּוֹרֵא עֲצֵי בְּשָׂמִים.

If it's grass or veggies, then it's בּוֹרֵא עִשְׂבֵי בְשָׂמִים.

The way to differentiate? See the end of Se'if 4

> וְהַסִימָן לֵידַע מַה הוּא עֵץ וּמַה הוּא יֶרֶק, כֹּל שֶׁהַגִּבְעוֹל הוּא קָשֶׁה כְּגִבְעוֹל שֶׁל פִּשְׁתָּן, וּמִתְקַיֵּם מִשָּׁנָה לְשָׁנָה וּמוֹצִיא עָלִין, זֶהוּ עֵץ. וְאוֹתָן שֶׁהַגִּבְעוֹל לְעוֹלָם רַךְ, הֲוֵי עִשְׂבֵי בְּשָׂמִים.‏

If the stem is at least as hard as flax, and it survives from one year to the next (like rose bushes) then it's a tree - and one says בּוֹרֵא עֲצֵי בְּשָׂמִים.

But if the stems are always soft, one says בּוֹרֵא עִשְׂבֵי בְשָׂמִים.

Comment: Where does it say in Kitzur Shulchan Aruch that grass is בּוֹרֵא עִשְׂבֵי בְשָׂמִים?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah - וְאוֹתָן שֶׁהַגִּבְעוֹל לְעוֹלָם רַךְ, הֲוֵי עִשְׂבֵי בְּשָׂמִים.‏ -  end of Se'if 4, as I already wrote. (Obviously, only if it has a good smell.)